# Changing UITabBarItem's Tint Color in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbaritem, uiappearance, tintcolor

I can't seem to change the tint color for `UITabBarItem`'s in iOS 9. I'm using objective-c and have tried using titleTextAttributes programmatically, and runtime attributes in storyboard as well. I've read through the documentation, but can't seem to figure this out. In fact I've even created a separate selectedState image, but again, it still tints it system blue.

Comment: try one of these, one should work:    [self tabBar].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [self view].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [self tabBar].translucent = false;
 [self tabBar].tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the appearance proxy like this:

```
[[UITabBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor black]];
```

This is working for me on iOS8 and iOS9. I have it in my app delegate - but you can put it in a base class if you like.

Comment: Wow. I've been trying this for the past few hours, but when you mentioned `base class` I realized I was entering it inside my view controller and not my tab bar controller. Silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark it as the correct answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `TabBar` property of tab bar controller and set tint color.

```
[youTabbarcontroller.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor anycolor]];
```